# Android : TabLayout not responding to clicks

Tags: android, android-layout

I have just created a layout that has a DrawerLayout and inside this there is the toolbar, tablayout and viewpager. However the in the tablayout, the tabs are not responding on clicking on them, but is changing on swiping. Here is the code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.HomeActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Content for screen without action bar-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/theme_color"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/theme_color"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/sub_theme_color"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navigation_drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_links"
    />
```

And in MainActivity.java

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

// Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Intializing tab-layout and viewpager for tabs
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tasks"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Updates"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Redeem"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    // Initializing viewpager to hold the tab-layout
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));


    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Now here is the weird part: It is clickable in Lollipop, but is not working in pre-lollipop version.

Comment: Consider using [ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.html). It already implements all callbacks for working with ViewPager. `tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager))`.

Comment: This comment could be improved, because `tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener` is deprecated. The recommended solution is now using `tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily solve this by checking the layout view in "design" tab of XML page. Better put the tablayout and viewpager inside a relativelayout.

The activity is fine.

Here is the corrected XML:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.HomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Content for screen without action bar-->

        <!-- Move toolbar above drawerlayout so that on opening drawer, it is visible -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/theme_color"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/theme_color"
                        android:elevation="6dp"
                        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/sub_theme_color"
                        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/shadow_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="4dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow" />

                </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_links"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```