# Making viewpager2 respond to tab click events

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I currently have my viewpager2 set up with tablayout using TabLayoutMediator. The tablayout works perfectly with swipe gesture, but I also want the tabs to respond to direct click events. This is mycode:

**OnCreate of Activity:**

```
        viewPager = accessBinding.pager;
        pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        accessBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        TabLayout tabLayout = accessBinding.accessTabs;
        TabLayout dotTabs = accessBinding.tabsDots;

        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
                (tab, position) -> tab.setText(TAB_TITLES[position])
        ).attach();

        new TabLayoutMediator(dotTabs, viewPager,
                (tab, position) -> {}
        ).attach();
```

**ScreenSlidePagerAdapter.java**:

```
private static class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
        // The number of tabs.
        private final int NUM_TABS = 2;
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fa) {
            super(fa);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            Log.d("lifecycle","viewpager createFragment");
            if(position==0)
                return new LoginFragment();
            else
                return new RegisterFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return NUM_TABS;
        }
    }
```

**Layout file:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/accesslayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/topguideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/access_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topguideline"
            app:tabGravity="fill" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_dots"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pager"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabPadding="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"/>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topguideline" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried using

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

but it doesn't work. Please help me to resolve this. I think viewPager implementation of tabselected is overriding my implementation but I need to figure out how to make viewpager respond to click events as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What helped me was changing the parent layout from a ConstraintLayout to a LinearLayout. Here's the post that helped me fix this issue:
[Android : TabLayout not responding to clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227966/android-tablayout-not-responding-to-clicks/35228122)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference

Answer (score 0):

Yes It also helped me remove constraint layout and use Linear Layout while using ViewPager2 with tablayout.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).